# Preventing/negating Frenzy at Brain Ladies (posible spoilers)

Tags: bloodborne

I'm trying to get past 3 brain ladies and I usually get grabbed while frenzied (which kills me off). Is there anything in the game that can negate frenzy or give a chance at survival when frenzied and grabbed?

By the way, I've got some anti-frenzy clothing, but it doesn't seem to do much because if I get grabbed I still do not have enough time to use 2 blood vials or the sedative after I am released.

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the brain ladies from inducing frenzy in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to stop the Winter Lanterns (which, according to the official guide is the real name for the brain ladies) from causing frenzy. You can, however, pretty significantly reduce the effect so you have enough time to kill them before the frenzy goes off. The main ways to do this are:

- The Beak Mask from the Crowfeather Armor set has very high frenzy resistance. This mask can be purchased from the bath messengers after acquiring the Crow Hunter Badge as part of the Eileen the Crow side quest.
- The Ashen Hunter Garb/Gloves/Trousers have the highest frenzy resist for the other clothing parts. These can be purchased from the insight vendor after you kill Djura in Old Yharnam.
- The Deep Sea Caryll Rune provides a huge amount of frenzy resistance. The medium power one that provides +200 frenzy RES can be found in the Forbidden woods down in the ravine that has two of the giant snake balls in it.

Some other tips:

- The Winter Lanterns need to have line of sight to cause frenzy. Hide behind rocks until you are ready to engage them.
- Make sure to have your sedatives equipped and ready to drink before you engage. Frenzy continues to build for a short while after the source is gone, so the time spent paging through your items might be just enough to cause it to trigger. D'oh!
- Heavy weapons like the Ludwig's Holy Blade in 2 handed mode can stun lock them and prevent them from grabbing you.
- If your timing is good, you can parry the grab attack and visceral them for huge damage. Since the Winter Lanterns only have the one grab attack, if you get the timing for this figured out, you can beat them pretty reliably.

Comment: One other useful thing to know is that each point of Insight reduces your Frenzy resist, so if you have quite a bit of it by this point, you can dump some at the Insight merchant and get your resistance back up.

Comment: The Caryll rune made world of difference!